# Access Ganache-CLI from several computers

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ganache

I'm trying to create a project where Person A puts some data on a Ganache-CLI instance, and Person B is capable of retrieving it. This worked fine on one server, because Ganache-CLI was running on localhost & could be accessed within the same server. However, now I'm trying to have both People (With  and  respectively) access the same Ganache-CLI instance (running on , and it's not working.

I first tried using `ganache-cli --host <Person A IP>` to connect to the instance already running, but that returned an error:

```
[Person A Server]
$ ganache-cli -m a --host <Person A IP>
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
... (printout)
Listening on <Person A IP>:8545
```

```
[Person B Server]
$ ganache-cli --host <Person A IP>
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available <Person A IP>:8545
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1313:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1516:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

I then realized this may be attempting to start a duplicate instance instead of connecting to the prior one, so I tried changing the IP I provided to my Web3 variables from `localhost` to `<Person A IP>` in my Node.js backend. However, it had trouble auto-detecting the provider this way:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

async function main() {
  const web3 = new Web3('<Person A IP>:8545')
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('<Person A IP>:8545')
  ... (cont.)
}
```

```
/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:75
            throw new Error('Can\'t autodetect provider for "' + provider + '"');
                  ^

Error: Can't autodetect provider for "<Person A IP>:8545"
    at RequestManager.setProvider (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:75:19)
    at new RequestManager (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:39:10)
    at Object.packageInit (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js:45:31)
    at new Web3 (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3/lib/index.js:39:10)
    at main (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/receive.js:13:16)
```

My last idea was to then create my `provider` variable first and explicitly pass that Object into the Web3 constructor, but this again failed:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

async function main() {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('<Person A IP>:8545')
  const web3 = new Web3(provider)
  ... (cont.)
}
```

```
/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-providers-http/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:66
        const error = new Error(msg);
                      ^

Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node <Person A IP>:8545.
    at Object.ConnectionError (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-providers-http/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:66:23)
    at Object.InvalidConnection (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-providers-http/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:36:21)
    at HttpProvider.send (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:110:25)
    at RequestManager.send (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:159:23)
    at sendRequest (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:624:42)
    at Eth.send [as getAccounts] (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:656:13)
    at main (/opt/ethereumPrograms/encryptedTransfer/src/receive.js:20:33)
```

How can I connect 2 computers at 2 different IP addresses to a single instance of Ganache-CLI? Is a `Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider` necessary or is there a Web3 HTTP provider option that will suffice?

Comment: That's not my question- I'm not trying to create several distinct instances of ganache.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand correctly. By default ganache listens in 127.0.0.1, so if you want for it to listen in the machine's IP then you have to configure the app, or the -h parameter if you use command line. If there's a proxy make sure the port 8545 is allowed.